# Mixing HibernateTemplate and JdbcTemplate in the same treatment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbctemplate

I currently work on a legacy application.

This application uses **spring (3.1.0.RELEASE)** and **hibernate (3.6.9.Final)**.

In some DAO, there is a mix of `hibernateTemplate` and `jdbcTemplate`.
I think that the developers finally use `jdbcTemplate` to simplify the select request.

What do you think of that ?
What are the potentials impacts of this type of mixture (cache pb ...)?

Have you ever encountered this kind of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with mixing jdbcTemplate (native sql) with hibernateTemplate (hql) in same transaction. Our team use that pattern in same (**rare**) situations. But it is important to have single method in single convention.

For example in one method you fetches set of IDs that satisfy some business logic (and this is easier of efficient to write this in SQL) and then you pass those IDs to other method that run some HQL using these IDs because it is more convenient there.

But for maintanance reasons it is good to have different conventions isolated in different methods. Of course this may be wrapped in on TX call.

Final note: when I decide to write project with hibernate I mean that hibernate is **dominant** technology and when some data can be fetched easier or significantly faster in other technology I will use other technology to do that.

Anyway you have to know all issues with hibernate caching and postponed flush and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your project to be successful create **code conventions** and rules that all developers  will follow.

Code should look like it was written by one person.

**Note**: so do not mix HibernateTemplate and JdbcTemplate.

Comment: I don't see how this answer the question.

Comment: Main idea of the answer: don't mix jdbcTemplate and hibernateTemplate.